# Disable/toggle smallcaps in the title

Tags: formatting, titles, capitalization, small-caps, amsart

I am using the `amsart` document class. I want to to change the text in the titles (such as in `\author`) to be written normally and not in small caps.

- How can I change this globally? That is, so that the text in all titles (`\title`, `\author`, `\section`, and so on) is written without small caps.
- How can I change this locally? That is, only change it in one place. If, for example, I include my email address in the `\author` field, I don't want it to be written in small caps. Wrapping the text inside `\textnormal` or `\textrm` does not work. Wrapping it inside `\lowercase` works, but I don't consider it a good solution.

Comment: A non-answer: in `amsart`, you should use the `\email` command to typeset your email address. It is not used inside the `\author` field but after it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While `amsart` uses smallcaps for section headings, it actually uses (full) capitals for `\author` and `\title`. Note that a title argument given in upper- and lowercase will produce capitals which are all of the same height.

The following MWE redefines the formatting in a way that only affects `\author`, `\title` and `\section`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@settitle}{\uppercasenonmath\@title}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@setauthors}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\section}{\scshape}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\author{Author, A.}
\title{And now for something completely different}
\maketitle

\section{A section}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you'd use `amsart` if you want to customize the style. Using `amsart` is basically just a way of telling it you want to use AMS style. It doesn't make sense to me to do that, but then deviate so significantly from its style. If it were me, I'd use the regular `article` class along with the `amsmath` package for the power of the AMS classes without the style, which will free you up to use, e.g., packages like `titling`, `fancyhdr` and `titlesec` for customizing the title, headers/footers and section headings.

Sure you *can* redefine some of the class's internals (lockstep tells you how), but it seems like a funny way of proceeding to me.

Comment: I can very well understand why people would like to customise `amsart` slightly. In general, I find `amsart` much better-looking than `article`; it's compact, looks professional, and is well-suited for documents with a lot of math – I don't know any other style that comes even close. The AMS style has some idiosyncratic features related to typesetting authors' affiliation, contact information, etc.; however, I think it is much easier to get a usable style by starting with `amsart` and tweaking slightly than by starting with `article` and re-doing everything.

Comment: Well, the thing is, Samuel *does* seem to want to re-do everything. Anyway, if I want compact, I load the `savetrees` package. `amsart` is problematic, because it isn't compatible with a lot of packages.

Comment: I don't understand why starting from `amsart` would be any different to starting from `article`. Naturally if it's less work for me to tweak `amsart` slightly, I would prefer that to massively tweaking `article`.