# Disable smallcaps within \textsc?

Tags: fonts, glossaries, small-caps

*How can I disable smallcaps within `\textsc{}`?*

I would like to be able to [disable/toggle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2820/6903) smallcaps on a local level so that something like `\textsc{o\textrm{open}mp}` looks like `\textsc{o}open\textsc{mp}`.  The reason for not doing the latter is to try to make use of the `glossaries` package with the `smallcaps` option for [abbreviations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9534/6903).  This automatically does the outer `\textsc{}` wrapping.

Comment: `\textsc{o\textup{open}mp}` should work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`\textsc` acts on the "shape" attribute; so changing again this attribute is what's needed: `\textup` exactly switches to "upright shape" (or Roman).

```
\textsc{a\textup{b}c}
```

will print "a" and "c" in small caps and "b" in the normal font.

Comment: This is broken with `newpxtext`.  One needs to use `\textulc{}` as [egreg suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155917/6903).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by egreg, you can use `\textup` instead of `textsc`.

One way to do this is to redefine the meaning of `\textrm`. I'd recommend limiting  it to within the scope where you want to apply this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
{% Group here so that this is only in effect locally in this group.
\let\OldTextrm\textrm%
\renewcommand{\textrm}[1]{\textup{#1}}%
%
These should be the same:\par
\textsc{o\textrm{open}mp}\par
\textsc{o}open\textsc{mp}\par
}

These should be different:\par
\textsc{o\textrm{open}mp}\par
\textsc{o}open\textsc{mp}\par
\end{document}
```