# \textup command not working inside \textsc

Tags: fonts

I believe it's going to be difficult getting a solution for my issue the way I have to put it, because I'm afraid I cannot provide an MWE for it.

The issue is that when I type something like `\textsc{\textup{upshape text} smallcaps text}`, what I get is everything typeset in small caps. I have been able to check that this issue is not dependent on the font I'm using.

I cannot provide an MWE because this happens in documents depending on a class where I'm loading a very long list of packages and where I'm doing a lot of processing. So, it'd be helpful if somebody could just say what may be going on here even if it is only as a possibility or as a guess, because everything else works fine.

Compilation is on `pdfLaTeX` and in the class I'm using `expl3` code.

EDIT: As for my intentions, I'm collecting some token lists and setting everything therein in small caps except for what I may have marked in the original text with `\textup`. Hope this helps.

EDIT 2: I've located the source of the problem. It boils down to something within the `biolinum` package. The next MWE replicates the problem:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{biolinum}

\begin{document}
\textsc{\textup{regular text} small caps}
\end{document}
```

Now, does anybody know what is the reason why this happens? And, of course, my appreciation to all those who have guessed, hinted, or provided any critical remarks.

Comment: I guess that you want `\MakeUppercase{text}` instead of `\textup{}`. Is this right? Your command `\textsc{\textup{upshape text} smallcaps text}` is working here.

Comment: Upshape (= textup) and scshape (textsc) change the same font feature, so the outer command wins.

Comment: `\textup` merely sets everything in an upright font that is otherwise in the same "family".  since there are very few font families that have small caps in anything *but* an upright orientation, you won't be able to see any difference.  in any event, it's not clear from your description exactly what you *do* want.  some more help, please ...

Comment: I'm sure my problem has to do with my own class at some point, but this is the only feature I seem to get wrong. When I compile the line in my post as a document of the `memoir` class, I get the right behavior. The thing is that I've got a lot of processing coded in my class and a long list of loaded packages. Hence, trying to find out from scratch where the problem is would be extremely time-consuming. I was mostly wondering if somebody else had been through a similar issue sometime.

Comment: @Sigur: No, what I need is what I mean. It's not `\MakeUppercase`, but the regular roman shape that you get by issuing `\textup` or `\upshape`, as opposed to the small caps shape.

Comment: @barbara beeton: The difference in the fonts I'm using is clearly discernible.

Comment: Use {\scshape.... } instead of \textsc{....}

Comment: @Marcos upright text is not opposed to small caps: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
\itshape\textsc{\textup{upshape text} smallcaps text}
\end{document}`

Comment: @cgnieder Note that `libertine` adds an axis, so `\scshape` and `\upshape` actually change different attributes. This is not true in the normal setup.

Comment: @Marcos I get “upshape text” in the normal font, and “smallcaps text” in small caps; there must be something else in your setup.

Comment: @egreg interesting! Someday I need to learn more about how NFSS works...

Comment: @egreg: Indeed. It's just that I really don't know where to start looking for it because everything else in the documents depending on that class looks fine.

Comment: It is important to note that the reason MWE's are called 'minimal' is *not* because they necessarily take a minimal amount of time or effort to create.  If you document is complex, it will take time (unless you get lucky).  Make a copy of the original file, and work slowly and methodically to reduce the amount of text in the document and then the number of packages required to recreate the problem.  Anything 'solution' you otherwise get is due to the excellent guessing abilities of some members, not becuase it is reasonable to expect that someone will guess the right answer.

Comment: @jon: Right. That's why I insisted on getting some guesses as to where the origin of the problem might be, considering in particular the possibility that somebody else was already familiar with the same issue.

Comment: @Marcos Start by removing packages which modify the default font setup - anything which loads a font, obviously, but also support packages such as `fontaxes` or `nfssext-cfr` which modify these kinds of commands. Use `\listfiles` to check a complete list of what's being loaded. Note that the mere fact that the problem occurs with different fonts doesn't show it isn't a result of your font choices since many different fonts use `fontaxes`, for example, to modify these kinds of commands.

Comment: Please check my EDIT 2.

Comment: Very nice MWE.  It is also reproducible with `\usepackage{libertine}` (the related serifed font).  A workaround would be to use `\textnormal` instead, which resets all attributes. ... But I see a real solution has been posted in the meantime!

Comment: @jon: Right, and a very informative one, as usual with egreg.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When NFSS2 (the current LaTeX font selection scheme) was designed, the developers decided for four "axes": encoding, family, weight and shape. They encoded four basic shapes

- upright
- italic
- slanted
- small caps

At the time, with the constraints imposed by the low memory computers available, this was probably sufficient. With *senno di poi* (as we say ‘hindsight’ in Italian), encoding small caps as a shape was a mistake. Packages such as `libertine` and `biolinum` load the `fontaxes` package that modifies NFSS2 in order to make room for a new axis. The command `\textup` only changes the “primary shape” attribute, but not the new axis that distinguishes between “primary” and “secondary” shapes, so the secondary shape remains small caps. The primary shape is for upright, italic and slanted.

This said, use `\textulc` (the corresponding declaration is `\ulcshape`), where `ulc` stands for “upper and lower case”.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{biolinum}

\begin{document}
\textsc{\textulc{regular text} small caps}
\end{document}
```

[image]