# Amsart Section title and figure in appendix

Tags: sectioning, appendices, amsart

OK Now I have two problems:
first the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
%for Abc format title and author list
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro{\endabstract}{\@setabstract}
\newcommand{\authorfootnotes}{\renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}}%
\makeatother
%for multi-line footnote format
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{\leftskip=2em\hskip-2em\@makefnmark#1}
\makeatother
%for left flushed section titles
\makeatletter
\def\specialsection{\@startsection{section}{3}%
  \z@{\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
%  {\normalfont\centering}}% DELETED
  {\normalfont}}% NEW
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
%  {\normalfont\scshape\centering}}% DELETED
  {\normalfont\scshape}}% NEW
\makeatother
%for formating subsection titles
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}  
\makeatletter
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{.1\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\itshape}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{Maya Devi Temple, Lumbini}\label{k}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{1} &
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{2}\\
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{3} &
  \includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth]{4}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Maya Devi Temple is an ancient Buddhist temple situated at the UNESCO World Heritage Site of Lumbini, Nepal. It is the main temple at Lumbini, a site traditionally considered the birthplace of Gautama Buddha. The temple stands adjacent to a sacred pool (known as Puskarni) and a sacred garden. The archaeological remains at the site were previously dated to the third-century BCE brick buildings constructed by Ashoka the Great.[1] A sixth-century BCE timber shrine was discovered in 2013.[2]}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: The output of above]
Now the first problem is that the apendix heading is coming below the figure itself which looks stupid. Also

the Section title is in caps (all of them) and I want it to be in Abc form, i.e. Not MAYA DEVI TEMPLE but "Maya devi temple"

Help!!! :s

i tried the following but no help:

```
\makeatletter
\def\specialsection{\@startsection{section}{3}%
  \z@{\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
%  {\normalfont\centering}}% DELETED
  {\normalfont}}% NEW
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}%
  \z@{.7\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
%  {\normalfont\scshape\centering}}% DELETED
  {\normalfont\scshape}}% NEW
\makeatother
```

Comment: PS I am in sort of a big hurry :(

Comment: "Sorry was a bit long as I dont know which of the packages is hindering.": Trim down MWE with unnecessary packages and commands to reproduce the errors, following http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl. If you have more math use `amsart` class otherwise stick with `article` or `report`.

Comment: ok removed all the stuff which wasnt causing problems, but left the formatting I have already done.... Also I am using amsart cause of lots of derivations

Comment: ok I solved the appendic title problem by writing \begin{figure}[htb]... the sections title problem still remains

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52118/amsart-cls-capitalizes-the-article-title-how-to-disable-it

Comment: Thanks @texenthusiast... I already saw it and have done something similar in my file. But cant figure out how to to do that for section title. I mean which is the handle for ABC to Abc?

Comment: To customize title in `amsart` http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2820/disable-toggle-smallcaps-in-the-title

Comment: tried that... the file wont compile :(

Comment: the link in the most recent comment by @texenthusiast (question 2820) really does hold the answer.  but instead of `\scshape` you want `\normalfont` or perhaps `\bfseries` if the heading should be bold.

Comment: well I tried this: \makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@settitle}{\uppercasenonmath\@title}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@setauthors}{\MakeUppercase}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\section}{\scshape}{}{}{}
\makeatother... the coming error is: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.1095 \patchcmd
                {\@settitle}{\uppercasenonmath\@title}{}{}{}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

section headings in `amsart` are set in small caps, not uppercase.
this can be overridden by using the following workaround:

```
\section{\textnormal{Maya Devi Temple, Lumbini}}\label{k}
```

other problems mentioned have already been reported as solved.